# maven "catch" execution - execute cleanup on failed build

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven build the launches a process (a database) using the exec plugin, then interacts with that process using several other plugin executions (the maven sql mojo) and then finally shuts down that process, using a 2nd execution od the exec plugin, bound to a later phase.

right now if any of the "middle" executions fail im left with a running process, which the build started but didnt get around to shutting down.

is there any "try/finally" mechanism in maven which i can use to clean up after a botched build?

Comment: Can you show the pom of that build? Apart from that to which life cycle phases did you bound the executions?

Comment: @khmarbaise - extract postgres *.tar.gz in generate-resources, start it up using a shell script in process-resources, various sql-plugin steps afterwards and stop it using shell scripts in prepare-package. the pom is several hundread lines and i think will just clutter up the question

Comment: That sounds like an integration test which means you are going into the wrong phase. There is a `pre-integration-test`, `integration-test` and `post-integration` life cycle phase which is after package phase and which is exactly for such purposes.

Comment: only its not an integration test. its part of a build that creates a database (schema, users, permissions etc) for a product deployment.

Comment: Ah..then completely wrong, cause maven is build tool and not a deployment tool. May be better to take a look at Chef, Puppet or may be Gradle. Or you might try Groovy Scripting for such thing.

Comment: @khmarbaise - the product uses an old-school installer, and across multiple OSs. also, this build is not done on the target machines, its done in advance and the results packaged into an installer. this rules out chef (linux-centric) and puppet (cant manage target machines). thank you for the interesting reading though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, if you're using this workflow for testing, you could use test plugin like surefire or failsafe to prevent failing of your build process. And validate results after database if down. In short, start db in pre-test phase, run tests in separate process using plugins I've mentioned above, stop db in port-test phase and validate test results in verify? phase.

[Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/)

Comment: nice suggestion, but im not doing this for testing.